# Reverse the content of data structure in swift

Tags: swift, data-structures, uicollectionview, reverse

I have a collection view which is fetched from API and parsed as data model.
It is as follows:

```
struct SearchDataModel: Codable,Equatable {

    static func == (lhs: SearchDataModel, rhs: SearchDataModel) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    let status: Int
    var data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable,Equatable {
    let userID: Int
    let name: String
    let image: String?
  //  let image: JSONNull?
    let userAddress: String?
    let id: Int
    let listingImage: String?
    let listingVideo: String?
    let listingTitle, listingAddress: String
    let listingPrice: Int
    let listingType: String
    let listingUse: String
    let listingSqft: String
    let listingBedsCount, listingBathsCount, listingParkingSpot: Int
    let listingDescription: String
    let featureListing: Int
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "user_id"
        case name, image
        case userAddress = "user_address"
        case id
        case listingImage = "listing_image"
        case listingVideo = "listing_video"
        case listingTitle = "listing_title"
        case listingAddress = "listing_address"
        case listingPrice = "listing_price"
        case listingType = "listing_type"
        case listingUse = "listing_use"
        case listingSqft = "listing_sqft"
        case listingBedsCount = "listing_beds_count"
        case listingBathsCount = "listing_baths_count"
        case listingParkingSpot = "listing_parking_spot"
        case listingDescription = "listing_description"
        case featureListing = "feature_listing"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}
```

This will display the content of the collection  view.I want to display it by reversing the contents in the collection view as the last item in the model as first item and so on.

Comment: Just inverse your model array, and reload the collectionview. `myArray.reverse(); myCollectionView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

My apologies in advanced if this is not a correct answer but it was a bit hard to understand your situation with the provided code format. But if the array `data` is what you are using as your data source, have you tried using the `reversed()` api; `data.reversed()`. This could solve your problem if I understood correctly.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/emptycollection/1688479-reversed

Comment: It is not simple array.it is in form of data structure

Comment: Show the code of `collectionView(cellForRowAt:)`, but I guess, you are doing something like `model.data[indexPath.row]`, no? Then, do `model = Model(status: model.status, data: model.data.reversed())`.